# ORACLE SQL pivot for non-aggregate like query

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table which has data like :-

`id name data
1  a    10
1  b    20
1  c    30
2  d    40
2  e    50`

Now, If I want to convert the rows into columns(giving them a unique name) and aggregate the data row (using xmlagg) ... How can I get output like

`id name_1 name_2 name_3 data
1  a      b      c      10,20,30
2  d      e             40,50`

So basically convert rows into columns and rename them and aggregate the data related to them.

Comment: How do you know what name to put in what column since order can vary?

Answer (score 1):

As an example: you can use listAgg or WM_Concat depending on version of Oracle

```
SELECt ID, wm_concat(data)
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID
```

you can also use a case statement but without knowing how you want to determine which names go in what of the 3 columns, I'm not hazarding a guess for it yet...

Answer (score 0):

For this type of query, you need to generate a sequential number and then do conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then name end) as name1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then name end) as name2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then name end) as name3,
       list_agg(data, ',') within group (order by name) as data
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by name) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by id;
```